# Using $.ajax to take me to a page with only results that matches the json data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to build a single page app that uses $.ajax.

Here is the json data:

```
{
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Denny's",
      "location": "Los Angeles",
      "cuisine": "American",
      "image_url": "http://www.coupons4utah.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/dennys-breakfast.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "restaurantId": 1,
      "name": "hamburger",
      "price": 10,
      "order_count": 0,
      "image_url": "http://kleberly.com/data_images/wallpapers/7/277047-hamburger.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "public": []
}
```

I have three buttons on my welcome screen and on of them is "Los Angeles". When I click "Los Angeles", I want it to take me to a page with only results with restaurants from that location. Every time I click it gets me nowhere. I'm stuck and been trying to code my way to make it work for a awhile. I am looking for a solution that will lead me into the right direction. Thanks!

```
var $body = $("body")
var $losAngeles = $('#los_angeles')



$losAngeles.on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

var location = data[i].location;

$.ajax({
    url: "/restaurants/:location",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:[{location: location}],
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data[i].location, function(i, location){
            console.log(data[i].location)
        })
    }
})




}

})

})
```

I have also tried coming up with this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/restaurants/:location',
    type: 'GET',
    data: [{location: location}],
    dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data){
    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var location = data[i].location
        if (location === "Los Angeles"){
        var name = data[i].name;
        var $LA = $('#LA');
        $LA.append('<li>' + name + '</li>' )
    }
    }
})

})

})
```

Still nothing.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to find out what actually happens? Is the AJAX request triggered at all?

Comment: In general, one of the best ways to debug is to use the Developer Tools of your browser. Both Chrome and Firefox (and to a lesser extent IE) toggle those tools when you hit F12. You can inspect the request/responses you're getting, set breakpoints on your code, and inspect variables at runtime to get a better picture of what's wrong.

I say this because you haven't mentioned what symptoms you see; just "it takes me nowhere".

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/restaurants/location", //changed
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:[{location: location}],
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.restaurants, function(i, location){ //changed
            console.log(data.restaurants[i].location); //changed
        })
    }
})
```

Also remember not to use ajax calls in loop. If multiple ajax calls are needed use [`.then`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) jQuery API.